# Как вызвать Java метод из NDK(JNI)?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, jni

В своем андроид приложении я использую NDK и у меня есть вот такой метод

```
static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    int size = bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
    bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
    return byteBuffer.array();
}
```

Теперь мне нужно достучатья к этому методу из `JNI`

Я написал вот такой метод

```
jbyteArray arr = env->CallStaticByteMethod(jniIds.helper_class, jniIds.get_bytes, image_obj);
```

Но, проблема в том, что метод `CallStaticByteMethod` возвращает `jbyte`, а мне нужно `jbyteArray`

Как правильно написать этот метод?

Comment: В java всё, кроме примитивов - есть объект. Следовательно `CallStaticObjectMethod` и каст к нужному типу. Если что, в NDK можно работать напрямую с памятью битмапа : [AndroidBitmap_lockPixels](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/bitmap#androidbitmap_lockpixels).